# Stack variable confusion in C

Tags: c

I am reading a very popular Stanford document* about linked lists in C.
There is a simple function in it that builds a simple LL with three members. The only thing I don't get and I am confused, is that it says it is storing the `head` pointer in a "local stack variable". But that `head` pointer is allocated in heap! Please take a look at the code and help me understand why it's a local stack variable?

```
/*
 Build the list {1, 2, 3} in the heap and store
 its head pointer in a local stack variable.
 Returns the head pointer to the caller.
*/
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {

struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;

head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

head->data = 1; // setup first node
head->next = second; // note: pointer assignment rule
second->data = 2; // setup second node
second->next = third;
third->data = 3; // setup third link
third->next = NULL;

// At this point, the linked list referenced by "head"
// matches the list in the drawing.
return head;
}
```

The document has provided following drawing for how the Linked List will look like in memory. I don't get why the `head` pointer is drawn in Stack area!

[image]

*: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf , pages 5 and 6

Comment: You are confusing "the `head` pointer" and "the thing the `head` pointer points to".

Comment: Would you please elaborate? The code is saying `head` pointer is local to the function. Which local variable? All variables(`head` , `second` and `third` are in heap.

Comment: That head pointer **variable**, *just like all the other variables in that function*, are automatic (in your vernacular, they live on the "stack"). Think of it this way. Upon scope exit, the variable `head` expires and ceases to exist. It's value is therefore lost. So, what would happen if you did *not* return the value in `head` as the function result to the caller, where the caller then stored it?  Unless someone else keeps that value (like you do via `return` to the caller) its lost forever, and with it, any chance to "get at" you initial node of your linked list.

Comment: @dandikain `head`, `second` and `third` do not live in the heap. Why do you think they live in the heap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But that head pointer is allocated in heap!

Not exactly, the memory portion to which the pointer points to is what is in heap. The pointer itself is stored in your function stack.

In the drawing, only `head` is shown in stack space, but the pointers `second` and `third` are also in the stack. The pointers here referring to the variable that holds an address. The address pointed by these variables is what is in heap.

Since `head->next` is assigned to `second`, you have two pointers to the same thing. And so forth with `third`. Note that `head->next` is a pointer stored in heap, and points to another heap memory address. It is the same as `second`, which is a pointer stored in stack with its address pointing to a heap memory location (again, the same as `head->next`). So another way to make a list is to allocate only the first (`head`) and use its `next` pointer to allocate the following element storing the address there directly. The drawback compared to what was used (with a direct pointer to the second and third elements) is that you lose this direct address. You'd need to visit the first and the second to find the address of the third.

Answer (score 1):

> it is storing the head pointer in a "local stack variable". But that
>   head pointer is allocated in heap!

Every node contains both a data part and pointer part. The above is saying that the pointer part of head will point to the first node which is 1 (located in the heap). However, the head pointer variable itself is located in the stack.

The purpose of the head pointer is simply to keep track of the first node and could also be used to access it through it's address which it holds.